# How to detect if windows7 is blocking my UDP server? How to request permission?

Tags: boost, boost-asio, windows-firewall

How can my program force the windows7 firewall to let me through, or raise an error?

My boost asio UDP peer-to-peer code was working.  Today it would not work.  I checked the firewall, and a.exe in my development directory was still authorized for private and public access.

On a hunch, I renamed a.exe to a1.exe, ran it, and windows asked me if I wanted to allow it to use the network.  Now it works again!

My guess is that windows7 remembers a checksum on a.exe, and when I compiled in new features it blocked network access, but it forgot to remove a.exe from the authorized list, so it did not give me the popup request.

For development I can just use a new name each time, but that would be a support nightmare when this rolls out to beta testers.

How do I check and/or request authorization within my code?

Answer (score 0):

Question is actually quite independent from **boost** framework.

Well, it seems there are different APIs that control windows firewall, depending on OS version (XP/Vista).
Here you have some useful resources with code examples:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa364726%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

http://www.vedivi.com/support/blog/72-configure-your-firewall-in-c.html

Also relevant:

[Why can't my application receive UDP packets when the Windows Base Filtering Engine service is enabled?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9602147/why-cant-my-application-receive-udp-packets-when-the-windows-base-filtering-eng)